# Passing a pointer from function C++ only change the value in function score

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm a newbee . I have doubt at some point. Hope anyone can help me. 
I pass the pointer as a parameter to the function. Inside the function I change it -> it has changed. But after the output is the same as before the function call . What wrong here ?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// works fine
void chgInt(int *p){
*p=10+*p;
}

// does not works!
void chgStr(char* name){
name="newName";
}
int main(void){

int i=6;
char *name="oldName";
cout<<"Name before: "<<name<<endl;
chgStr(name);
cout<<"Name After "<<name<<endl;
cout<<"integer is :"<<i<<" and f(integer) is :";
chgInt(&i);
cout<<i<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: c is not c++..c++ is not c

Comment: You pass the pointer by value, i.e. it is a local copy inside the function that you change. And why are you trying to *emulate* pass by reference? C++ have native references.

Comment: `const char *name="oldName";`... `void chgStr(const char* &name){`

Comment: why in the first case it work , but the second doesn't

Comment: If you want to change the pointer, you need to use double pointer.

Comment: Search for *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: i know i can pass by reference to change the value, but i still dont understand . in the first case , the pointer p will hold address of variable i (&i) and i can you *p to change the value of i , but why in the second case it doesnt work like this . does pointer name in the function void 'chgStr(char* name)' will hold address of name ?

Answer (score 0):

if you use c++ you should use the library std::string not string.h (that used in c) but if you use c then you should use printf() and such c functions

about the question:
i don't want to miss lead you but you can go and read about pointers and pointer to pointer (and in that case pointers to string(chars array))

but in general the problem is that you change the value of the string but it's not the same string in the memory only in the value.

you can fix that by changing the function to

```
void chgStr(char** name){
*name="newName";
}
```

and passing the string by it's pointer

```
chgStr(&name);
```

Comment: thank you , but why i dont need the pointer to pointer for the integer (i) , i thought "name" in the function  will hold the address ( value ) of "name" i passed by pointer void chgStr(char **name) and i can use pointer name to change the value . What i miss here ?

Comment: that's why i wrote you to go research about that pointer to pointer stuff

Comment: but basiclly its just because even if its an array(that is also a pointer) you pass its like sending a regular int(consepltly)

Comment: its like if were passing i to the function instead of &i